# clip-out rainbow animation with svg-icon

Tags: html, css, svg

i'd like to animate a simple company-logo for a website-header by using a rainbow animation as a background effect. so the rainbow-animation should be visible trough the transparent icon which sits on a white background. unfortunately, i can't find any code examples of how to do it with an icon (.svg).

do i have to create some kind of svg path (and if, how do i do that based on that image?) or is there a much simpler method where i could just use the black icon on a white background and use a css blending-mode with a .png-file?

here's on example of a rainbow effect i'd like to use:
https://codepen.io/nohoid/pen/kIfto

```css
.wrapper { 
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  left:0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  position: absolute;
background: linear-gradient(124deg, #ff2400, #e81d1d, #e8b71d, #e3e81d, #1de840, #1ddde8, #2b1de8, #dd00f3, #dd00f3);
background-size: 1800% 1800%;

-webkit-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-z-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
-o-animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;
  animation: rainbow 18s ease infinite;}

@-webkit-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-moz-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@-o-keyframes rainbow {
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
@keyframes rainbow { 
    0%{background-position:0% 82%}
    50%{background-position:100% 19%}
    100%{background-position:0% 82%}
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper"></div>
```

and i guess it has to be a modified version of this code?:
https://w3bits.com/rainbow-text/

and here's the company-icon i'm trying to use:
https://ibb.co/G3gDNsk

best regards
max

UPDATE: this is how the code should look like so far, according to enxaneta however there is one major issue why it's not working. the path is way to complex for what it is, but i don't know how to fix this at all.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>done all</title>
  <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grd" x2="100%" y2="100%" > 
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff2400"></stop>
        <stop offset="11%" stop-color="#e81d1d"></stop>
        <stop offset="22%" stop-color="#e8b71d"></stop>
        <stop offset="33%" stop-color="#e3e81d"></stop>
        <stop offset="44%" stop-color="#1de840"></stop>
        <stop offset="55%" stop-color="#2b1de8"></stop>
        <stop offset="66%" stop-color="#ff2400"></stop>
        <stop offset="77%" stop-color="#dd00f3"></stop>
        <stop offset="88%" stop-color="#e8b71d"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#dd00f3"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
  <mask id="msk">
   <path d='M 18.23,553.81
           C 16.54,552.11 189.40,380.94 204.90,365.46
             204.90,365.46 221.86,348.50 221.86,348.50
             220.31,346.94 228.38,340.00 230.65,339.72
             235.11,339.12 230.19,343.26 229.65,344.08
             226.40,349.10 220.20,353.53 215.95,357.78
             215.95,357.78 106.44,467.41 106.44,467.41
             106.44,467.41 46.03,527.60 46.03,527.60
             41.78,531.85 22.94,556.61 16.46,552.39
             6.94,546.05 -1.91,561.39 7.54,567.69
             24.22,578.77 35.87,563.05 46.49,552.36
             46.49,552.36 102.19,496.66 102.19,496.66
             102.19,496.66 229.97,368.86 229.97,368.86
             239.46,359.37 256.39,347.44 248.84,331.97
             238.86,311.36 219.95,325.45 209.40,336.00
             209.40,336.00 88.52,456.79 88.52,456.79
             88.52,456.79 22.38,522.90 22.38,522.90
             11.76,533.52 -10.48,550.13 5.70,566.31
             13.77,574.38 26.27,561.88 18.23,553.81 Z
           M 224.71,333.10
           C 228.62,329.19 234.96,329.19 238.88,333.10
             238.88,333.10 238.90,333.13 238.90,333.13
             242.82,337.04 242.82,343.39 238.90,347.30
             238.90,347.30 26.14,560.08 26.14,560.08
             22.23,563.99 15.88,563.99 11.97,560.08
             11.97,560.08 11.94,560.05 11.94,560.05
             8.03,556.14 8.03,549.79 11.94,545.88
             11.94,545.88 224.71,333.10 224.71,333.10 Z
           M 313.99,554.87
           C 310.17,553.06 344.27,486.07 347.07,480.12
             347.07,480.12 403.72,360.15 403.72,360.15
             400.57,353.50 410.27,339.83 415.76,334.66
             419.55,331.12 413.77,334.66 419.69,333.95
             423.83,329.56 428.96,327.79 432.72,327.79
             432.72,327.79 378.76,442.09 378.76,442.09
             378.76,442.09 327.38,527.60 327.38,527.60
             325.68,531.15 317.89,555.54 311.87,554.06
             300.82,551.33 296.08,568.22 307.16,571.12
             325.15,575.55 330.64,561.99 336.83,548.85
             336.83,548.85 364.49,490.25 364.49,490.25
             364.49,490.25 428.04,355.69 428.04,355.69
             433.46,344.18 441.78,329.27 392.35,341.53
             380.45,313.80 359.78,355.34 359.78,355.34
             359.78,355.34 299.23,483.59 299.23,483.59
             299.23,483.59 303.80,530.44 303.80,530.44
             298.06,542.62 287.19,562.94 343.49,562.94
             315.13,574.98 324.30,559.72 313.99,554.87 Z
           M 408.18,329.91
           C 408.18,329.91 408.18,329.91 408.18,329.91
             410.55,324.90 416.52,322.76 421.52,325.12
             421.52,325.12 421.55,325.14 421.55,325.14
             426.56,327.50 428.70,333.47 426.34,338.48
             426.34,338.48 426.34,338.48 426.34,338.48
             426.34,338.48 322.85,557.73 322.85,557.73
             320.48,562.73 314.51,564.87 309.51,562.51
             309.51,562.51 309.48,562.50 309.48,562.50
             304.47,560.13 302.33,554.16 304.69,549.16
             304.69,549.16 408.18,329.91 408.18,329.91 Z
           M 235.50,336.22
           C 233.09,336.22 234.33,82.58 234.33,60.02
             234.33,60.02 234.33,33.46 234.33,33.46
             234.33,30.84 232.84,22.84 234.33,17.60
             222.50,22.95 240.35,17.60 247.89,17.60
             267.58,17.60 240.35,17.60 240.35,17.60
             240.35,17.60 240.35,295.88 240.35,295.88
             240.35,302.26 244.70,334.83 236.81,336.53
             223.39,330.09 256.14,341.24 253.87,356.29
             249.87,372.83 229.72,372.83 214.50,372.83
             214.50,372.83 214.50,43.24 214.50,43.24
             214.50,29.89 218.32,8.68 202.92,2.20
             180.26,-7.37 176.72,18.20 176.72,33.46
             176.72,33.46 176.72,310.33 176.72,310.33
             176.72,325.45 172.44,353.92 195.59,353.92
             246.90,353.92 246.90,336.22 235.50,336.22 Z
           M 235.53,9.49
           C 241.07,9.49 245.55,13.98 245.55,19.51
             245.55,19.51 245.55,335.05 245.55,335.05
             245.55,340.58 241.07,345.07 235.53,345.07
             235.53,345.07 235.50,345.07 235.50,345.07
             235.50,345.07 235.50,345.07 235.50,345.07
             229.96,345.07 225.48,340.58 225.48,335.05
             225.48,335.05 225.48,19.51 225.48,19.51
             225.48,13.98 229.96,9.49 235.50,9.49
             235.50,9.49 235.50,9.49 235.50,9.49
             235.50,9.49 235.53,9.49 235.53,9.49 Z
           M 417.28,336.22
           C 414.87,336.22 416.11,82.58 416.11,60.02
             416.11,60.02 416.11,33.46 416.11,33.46
             416.11,30.84 414.62,22.84 416.11,17.60
             404.28,22.95 422.13,17.60 429.67,17.60
             449.36,17.60 422.13,17.60 422.13,17.60
             422.13,17.60 422.13,295.88 422.13,295.88
             422.13,302.26 426.48,334.83 418.59,336.53
             405.17,330.09 437.92,341.24 435.66,356.29
             431.65,372.83 411.51,372.83 396.28,372.83
             396.28,372.83 396.28,43.24 396.28,43.24
             396.28,29.89 400.11,8.68 384.70,2.20
             362.04,-7.37 358.50,18.20 358.50,33.46
             358.50,33.46 358.50,310.33 358.50,310.33
             358.50,325.45 354.22,353.92 377.37,353.92
             428.68,353.92 428.72,336.22 417.28,336.22 Z
           M 417.31,9.49
           C 422.85,9.49 427.33,13.98 427.33,19.51
             427.33,19.51 427.33,335.05 427.33,335.05
             427.33,340.58 422.85,345.07 417.31,345.07
             417.31,345.07 417.28,345.07 417.28,345.07
             411.74,345.07 407.26,340.58 407.26,335.05
             407.26,335.05 407.26,19.51 407.26,19.51
             407.26,13.98 411.74,9.49 417.28,9.49
             417.28,9.49 417.31,9.49 417.31,9.49 Z
           M 597.68,333.21
           C 595.27,333.21 596.51,81.44 596.51,58.82
             596.51,58.82 596.51,33.53 596.51,33.53
             596.51,30.91 595.06,22.66 596.51,17.60
             584.65,22.98 602.60,17.60 610.07,17.60
             629.83,17.60 602.60,17.60 602.60,17.60
             602.60,17.60 602.60,292.73 602.60,292.73
             602.60,298.89 606.92,331.97 599.06,333.56
             585.64,327.11 618.39,338.27 616.13,353.39
             612.13,369.93 591.91,369.93 576.65,369.93
             576.65,369.93 576.65,42.49 576.65,42.49
             576.65,28.97 580.40,7.65 564.01,1.88
             542.13,-5.81 538.87,17.92 538.87,32.90
             538.87,32.90 538.87,307.21 538.87,307.21
             538.87,322.33 534.58,350.91 557.74,350.91
             609.01,350.91 609.01,333.21 597.68,333.21 Z
           M 597.68,9.49
           C 597.68,9.49 597.68,9.49 597.68,9.49
             603.21,9.49 607.70,13.98 607.70,19.51
             607.70,19.51 607.70,332.04 607.70,332.04
             607.70,337.57 603.21,342.06 597.68,342.06
             597.68,342.06 597.68,342.06 597.68,342.06
             597.68,342.06 597.65,342.06 597.65,342.06
             597.65,342.06 597.65,342.06 597.65,342.06
             592.11,342.06 587.63,337.57 587.63,332.04
             587.63,332.04 587.63,19.51 587.63,19.51
             587.63,13.98 592.11,9.49 597.65,9.49
             597.65,9.49 597.65,9.49 597.65,9.49
             597.65,9.49 597.68,9.49 597.68,9.49 Z
           M 780.10,555.30
           C 777.45,555.30 778.79,123.90 778.79,85.34
             778.79,85.34 778.79,41.29 778.79,41.29
             778.79,36.26 776.49,24.54 778.79,20.04
             776.21,12.50 787.01,27.51 787.01,27.51
             787.01,27.51 787.01,487.84 787.01,487.84
             787.01,495.70 792.32,553.91 783.46,555.68
             770.05,549.24 802.80,560.39 800.53,579.69
             795.68,596.09 755.78,596.09 738.07,596.09
             738.07,596.09 738.07,28.33 738.07,28.33
             738.07,18.70 720.08,21.03 713.85,13.95
             702.70,-17.32 683.37,31.05 713.36,23.30
             713.36,42.14 713.36,51.63 713.36,51.63
             713.36,51.63 713.36,503.81 713.36,503.81
             713.36,520.52 704.19,575.12 732.37,575.12
             791.50,573.00 791.50,555.30 780.10,555.30 Z
           M 780.10,8.96
           C 780.10,8.96 780.10,8.96 780.10,8.96
             785.58,8.96 790.02,13.40 790.02,18.87
             790.02,18.87 790.02,554.23 790.02,554.23
             790.02,554.23 790.02,554.23 790.02,554.23
             790.02,559.71 785.58,564.15 780.10,564.15
             780.10,564.15 780.10,564.15 780.10,564.15
             780.10,564.15 779.85,564.15 779.85,564.15
             779.85,564.15 779.85,564.15 779.85,564.15
             774.38,564.15 769.94,559.71 769.94,554.23
             769.94,554.23 769.94,554.23 769.94,554.23
             769.94,554.23 769.94,18.87 769.94,18.87
             769.94,13.40 774.38,8.96 779.85,8.96
             779.85,8.96 779.85,8.96 779.85,8.96
             779.85,8.96 780.10,8.96 780.10,8.96 Z' fill="white"></path> 
  </mask>
  </defs>
  <g style="mask: url(#msk)">
  <rect x="-200" width="800" height = "573" fill='url(#grd)' >
     <animateTransform 
     attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="0,0; 200,0; 0,0" 
        dur="10s" 
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is my solution: I'm using svg masks to cut out the rainbow. In order to animate the rainbow I'm using a very long rect with a rainbow fill. I'm translating this rect to and fro using `animateTransform`. The colors I'm using are from the pen you link.

I hope this is what you need.

```css
svg{border:1px solid;width:90vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 24 24'><title>done all</title>
  <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grd" x2="100%" y2="100%" > 
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff2400"></stop>
        <stop offset="11%" stop-color="#e81d1d"></stop>
        <stop offset="22%" stop-color="#e8b71d"></stop>
        <stop offset="33%" stop-color="#e3e81d"></stop>
        <stop offset="44%" stop-color="#1de840"></stop>
        <stop offset="55%" stop-color="#2b1de8"></stop>
        <stop offset="66%" stop-color="#ff2400"></stop>
        <stop offset="77%" stop-color="#dd00f3"></stop>
        <stop offset="88%" stop-color="#e8b71d"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#dd00f3"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
  <mask id="msk">
   <path d='M18 7l-1.41-1.41-6.34 6.34 1.41 1.41 6.34-6.34zm4.24-1.41l-10.58 10.58-4.18-4.17-1.41 1.41 5.59 5.59 12-12-1.42-1.41zm-21.83 7.82l5.59 5.59 1.41-1.41-5.58-5.59-1.42 1.41z' fill="white"></path> 
  </mask>
  </defs>
  <g style="mask: url(#msk)">
  <rect x="-200" width="224" height = "224" fill='url(#grd)' >
     <animateTransform 
     attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="0,0; 200,0; 0,0" 
        dur="10s" 
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

In this update I'm using OP's path.

```css
svg{border:1px solid; width:100vh}
```

```html
<svg viewBox="0 0 259 190"><title>done all</title>
  <defs>
     <linearGradient id="grd" x2="100%" y2="100%" > 
        <stop offset="0%" stop-color="#ff2400"></stop>
        <stop offset="11%" stop-color="#e81d1d"></stop>
        <stop offset="22%" stop-color="#e8b71d"></stop>
        <stop offset="33%" stop-color="#e3e81d"></stop>
        <stop offset="44%" stop-color="#1de840"></stop>
        <stop offset="55%" stop-color="#2b1de8"></stop>
        <stop offset="66%" stop-color="#ff2400"></stop>
        <stop offset="77%" stop-color="#dd00f3"></stop>
        <stop offset="88%" stop-color="#e8b71d"></stop>
        <stop offset="100%" stop-color="#dd00f3"></stop>
        </linearGradient>
  <mask id="msk">
  <g fill="white">
 <path d="M82.908,66.963c0,13.656,0.293,27.323-0.197,40.963
  c-0.13,3.606-1.778,8.003-4.258,10.547c-18.482,18.958-37.344,37.546-56.108,56.229c-1.053,1.049-2.228,2.576-3.467,2.703
  c-2.113,0.216-5.052,0.212-6.277-1.038c-1.141-1.165-0.869-4.14-0.509-6.193c0.224-1.278,1.677-2.414,2.729-3.464
  c17.794-17.769,35.544-35.581,53.491-53.194c2.879-2.825,3.889-5.643,3.863-9.589c-0.162-25.312-0.095-50.628-0.062-75.942
  c0.003-2.149-0.281-4.591,0.615-6.368c0.949-1.882,2.993-4.146,4.841-4.433c3.271-0.508,5.05,2.112,5.257,5.317
  c0.193,2.985,0.079,5.992,0.081,8.989C82.911,43.314,82.908,55.139,82.908,66.963z"/>
 <path d="M134.135,67.524c0,13.986,0.044,27.973-0.051,41.959
  c-0.014,1.923-0.347,4.012-1.152,5.734c-8.87,18.968-17.852,37.883-26.844,56.793c-0.777,1.635-1.494,3.862-2.86,4.519
  c-1.983,0.951-4.805,1.446-6.739,0.722c-1.163-0.435-1.948-3.617-1.77-5.454c0.215-2.209,1.557-4.338,2.545-6.438
  c7.993-16.993,16.092-33.937,23.955-50.988c1.202-2.608,1.901-5.696,1.918-8.566c0.146-25.143,0.055-50.286,0.124-75.429
  c0.009-3.142,0.108-6.413,1.005-9.371c0.491-1.622,2.967-3.979,4.137-3.764c2.002,0.367,3.909,2.292,5.398,3.969
  c0.727,0.818,0.561,2.552,0.563,3.872c0.034,14.147,0.021,28.295,0.021,42.443C134.302,67.524,134.219,67.524,134.135,67.524z"/>
 <path d="M236.904,97.508c0,23.484,0.017,46.968-0.027,70.452
  c-0.004,2.139,0.213,4.638-0.778,6.317c-1.103,1.868-3.404,3.981-5.311,4.11c-1.435,0.097-3.737-2.516-4.446-4.382
  c-0.905-2.386-0.788-5.232-0.783-7.881c0.087-46.296,0.225-92.593,0.355-138.889c0.005-1.665-0.097-3.351,0.128-4.989
  c0.429-3.137,2.161-5.855,5.443-5.072c2.007,0.479,3.778,2.987,5.081,4.963c0.697,1.058,0.202,2.917,0.202,4.415
  c0.006,23.651,0.004,47.304,0.004,70.955C236.816,97.508,236.86,97.508,236.904,97.508z"/>
 <path d="M185.084,66.376c0,13.488,0.006,26.977-0.008,40.465
  c-0.002,1.495,0.436,3.379-0.289,4.401c-1.293,1.822-3.18,4.057-5.083,4.341c-1.436,0.214-3.658-2.087-4.823-3.761
  c-0.829-1.191-0.636-3.201-0.638-4.846c-0.032-26.477-0.044-52.954,0.017-79.431c0.005-2.303,0.055-4.841,1.004-6.83
  c0.76-1.593,3.046-3.624,4.425-3.466c1.825,0.209,3.826,2.09,4.988,3.777c0.804,1.168,0.393,3.225,0.396,4.884
  C185.094,39.399,185.084,52.888,185.084,66.376z"/>
</g> 
  </mask>
  </defs>
   <g style="mask: url(#msk)">
  <rect x="-2000" y="0" width="2259" height = "2000" fill='url(#grd)' >
     <animateTransform 
     attributeType="XML" 
        attributeName="transform" 
        type="translate"
        values="0,0; 2000,0; 0,0" 
     
        dur="10s" 
        repeatCount="indefinite" />
  </rect>
  </g>
</svg>
```

#### UPDATE

the OP is asking:

> may i ask how you adjusted the path so i can do it myself if ever needed?

In this case it's important to make sure that the svg viewBox is as big as or bigger than your path's bounding box. To know the bounding box of a path or of a group of paths you may use the getBBox() method.

Also the rect filled with the gradient should be much bigger than the path's bounding box. In this case is 2000 units + the bounding box width = 2259.

The `animateTransform` is translating the rect from 0 to 2000 and back to 0.

Comment: hey enxaneta,

thank you very much for your post! i think that's exactly what i'm looking for, however, i'm not sure how to get my .svg icon in there. i opened up my svg in the text editor and it showed me multiple "path d" but none of them worked when i tried them with your code. any simple advice of how to get the right path d for my icon?

here's the file: https://wetransfer.com/downloads/ed15990c805f0619be4dfa413cd0f66920190224153916/d3a4f1

huge thanks in advance!

Comment: and: is this actually possible with just a simple .png with a transparent cutout, too? if so, that would be a lot more simple since the icon itself isn't moving so no animation needed for that.

Comment: Try this and if it doesn't work ask again. Mean while please consider to accept my answer if you think it helped.

Comment: thanks for the quick reply. did you attach a link or something? because the only thing i see is "try this and if it doesn't work ask again"

Comment: No, What I mean is "try what you have in mind", because I suppose you like to try things. If it doesn't work _attach code_ and ask again

Comment: i attached the code as a new answer to make it more overseeable

Comment: I've updated my answer this time using a modified version of your path

Comment: i can't thank you enough enxaneta, you're the best! work's like a charm! may i ask how you adjusted the path so i can do it myself if ever needed?

also, i just added the code in my website-header. it works as intended, the only thing weird is that as soon as i hover over the element the background animation stops until i refresh the page. any idea why that is?

Comment: nevermind, i'm stupid. just took a second look at your code and it's written there clearly: end="mouseover". i'll just get rid of that then. sorry..

Comment: Sorry about that. You can delete the `begin` and the `calcMode` attributes

Comment: I've updated again my answer  with an explanation. Please take a look